# Want one row of data but group by does not appear to be having that affect

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to just return one row of data with the sum of data and also  group by production plan item id ideally what i want is a row showing me that field and the sum qty value so it should read

```
ProductionPlanItemId    QtyCompleted
5865406                 3  

/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT [CompletedPrintedId]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[ProductionPlanId]
      ,[QtyCompleted]
      ,[SubAssembledQty]
      ,[QtyRequired]
      ,[ProductionPlanItemID]
      ,[SOPOrderReturnLineId]
FROM [CompletedPrinted]
where DocumentNo='0000027084'  and ProductionPlanItemID='5865406'
GROUP BY 
      [ProductionPlanItemID]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[ProductionPlanId]
      ,[QtyCompleted]
      ,[SubAssembledQty]
      ,[QtyRequired]
      , [CompletedPrintedId]
      ,[SOPOrderReturnLineId]
```

The Colum schema  is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CompletedPrinted](
    [CompletedPrintedId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](66) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [StartDateTIme] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProductionPlanId] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [SopLineItemId] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [Detail] [nvarchar](1002) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [isActive] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [DocumentNo] [nvarchar](102) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [StockCode] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [StockDescription] [text] NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [QtyCompleted] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [SubAssembledQty] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [QtyRequired] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [ProductionPlanItemID] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [SOPOrderReturnLineId] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
)
```

I have created a sql fiddle below with the sample data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8927c/2

[image]

**Edit 2**
Sorry I should have stated I need the other columns to be there.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what a `GROUP BY` is used for. A `GROUP BY` is *normally* used when you are aggregating at least one column (such as using the `SUM`, `MAX`, `COUNT` functions). Having a `GROUP BY` with no aggregate functions is rather pointless and it would be far more succinct to use the `DISTINCT` keyword. Of course, that isn't what you are after here, but it worth noting for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use row_number() if you need one row per ProductionPlanId

```
select * from (SELECT [CompletedPrintedId]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[ProductionPlanId]
      ,[QtyCompleted]
      ,[SubAssembledQty]
      ,[QtyRequired]
      ,[ProductionPlanItemID]
      ,[SOPOrderReturnLineId]
      ,row_number() over(partition by ProductionPlanId
                          order by QtyCompleted) rn
  FROM [CompletedPrinted]
  where DocumentNo='0000027084'  and ProductionPlanItemID='5865406'
) a where a.rn=1
```

[demo link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8927c/4)

but it seems you just need `sum()`

```
select    
      [ProductionPlanId]
      ,sum(QtyCompleted) 

  FROM [CompletedPrinted]
  where DocumentNo='0000027084'  and ProductionPlanItemID='5865406'
  group by ProductionPlanId
```

output

```
 ProductionPlanId   QtyCompleted
  5865405             3
```

as you need all column as well so try below

/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/

```
 with cte as
  ( select    
     c.ProductionPlanId
      ,sum(QtyCompleted)  as QtyCompleted

  FROM [CompletedPrinted] c
  where DocumentNo='0000027084'  and ProductionPlanItemID='5865406'
  group by ProductionPlanId
    ) , cte2 as
    (select cte.QtyCompleted as MQtyCompleted,c2.*,
       row_number()over(partition by c2.ProductionPlanId order by cte.QtyCompleted) rn
       from
    cte join CompletedPrinted c2
    on cte.ProductionPlanId=c2.ProductionPlanId
     ) select * from cte2 where rn=1
```

Comment: the issue with just sum is that i cant have the other columns in it then ;-)

Comment: @Dave do you need all other columns?

Comment: yes and also when i run your fiddle it doesnt return the result u showed in the output

Comment: @Dave http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8927c/12 this is the fiddle for 2nd query

Answer (score 0):

Exclude all columns except `ProductionPlanId` in `GROUP BY` clause & do aggregation :

```
SELECT [ProductionPlanId], SUM([QtyCompleted])
FROM [CompletedPrinted]
WHERE DocumentNo = '0000027084' AND ProductionPlanItemID='5865406'
GROUP BY [ProductionPlanId];
```